# Avoid memory allocations for formatting paths

Tags: c, memory, path

I want to avoid memory allocations to construct the path for device

```
    char *device;
    const char *p;
    char buf[PATH_MAX];
```

Witch method is memory less use

PATH_MAX

```
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf) - 1, "/dev/%s", p);
    device = &buf[0];
```

or

asprintf

```
    asprintf(&device, "/dev/%s", p);
```

Comment: I would try strcat...

Comment: Funny: `asprintf()` allocates memory with `malloc()`, yet you want to avoid memory allocations. The `char buf[PATH_MAX]` also allocates memory, but not via `malloc()`. Maybe you meant dynamic memory allocation; if so, you can't use `asprintf()`. You can perfectly well use `snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), ...)` — you don't need to subtract 1. If PATH_MAX is defined (it need not be), then it is going to be larger than the space you need for `/dev/%s` for any plausible value of `p`. So, `asprintf()` will allocate less memory than the fixed size buffer, but you'll have to release what it does allocate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

asprintf allocates the memory needed dynamically while the first method declares a (probably) larger buffer on the stack. So asprintf uses exactly as much bytes as needed and char buf[MAX] does not. But you have to make sure you free the memory allocated in asprintf yourself

Answer (score 1):

The most significant difference is not the few bytes of memory, but where the memory is coming from and how you need to handle it afterwards.

- `buf` is allocated on the stack, and if you return from the function your snippet is coming from, then `device` will not point to a valid memory location anymore. Corruption or a crash will be the most likely outcome. On the other hand, if you only use `device` inside the function, you won't have to free it afterwards. Also, stack-allocated memory is more efficient in general, although caching and optimizations may equal the picture.
- `asprintf` allocates the memory from the heap, which means you can safely pass it around to all parts of your program as long as it runs. The downside is that you have to `free` it when you don't need it anymore or it will hang around forever and you have a memory leak (which might matter or not, depending on how many unfreed buffers are floating around). It's then your responsibility to free the memory.

But to answer your question: `asprintf` will allocate no more bytes than needed, and you don't have to specify a maximum size which might "feel" better. You probably shouldn't worry about a few bytes of stack memory extra though. How big is `PATH_MAX`? Half a kilobyte?

Comment: PATH_MAX is a POSIX value; it can be found through `pathconf()` and sometimes via `<limits.h>`.  It's minimum value is POSIX_PATH_MAX, and the value of that is just 256.  PATH_MAX is often 1024.